# How to pass @RequestParams into a nested POJO when using kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, url, kotlin

I have a method like:

```
fun all(@Validated pagination: Pagination)
```

the `pagination` looks like

```
class Pagination(
    @field:NotNull(message = "page must be => 0")
    @field:Min(0, message = "page must be => 0")
    val page: Int = 0,
    @field:Min(1, message = "size must be  0 =< size >= 12")
    @field:Max(12, message = "size must be  0 =< size >= 12")
    val size: Int = 12,
    @field:Valid
    val sort: Sort = Sort("title", "ASC")
)
```

what itself has a

```
class Sort(
    @field:NotBlank
    val by: String,
    @field:NotBlank
    @field:Pattern(regexp = "^(asc|ASC)|(desc|DESC)$")
    val order: String
)
```

If I call the endpoint with `?page=0&size=2&sort.by=title&sort.order=DESC`
both, `page`and `size` are taken into account, but not `sort.order` and `sort.by`.
From what I'vre read this should be doable, but because I use Kotlin I may overlook something?